# Change WooCommerce order status based on approved status and specific order item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I try to change a WooCommerce order status to "Processing" when the current status is "Approved" and the order includes a specific product ( id = 10).

I have attempted the code below but it is not working.  I am quite new to php and would appreciate any guidance!

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'ts_auto_complete_business_cards');

function ts_auto_complete_business_cards($order_id)
{

    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    global $product;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ($order->data['status'] == 'approved') {
        $items=$order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            if ($product_id!="10")
            {
                $order->update_status( 'completed' );
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `woocommerce_order_status_changed` has 4 parameters
- This line -> `if ($product_id!="10")` says NOT equal, you also compare with a string and not with a numerical value

Try it this way

```php
function action_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {

    // Compare
    if( $old_status === 'approved' ) {
        // Get items
        $items = $order->get_items();

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            // Get product id
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

            if ($product_id == 10 ) {
                $order->update_status( 'processing' );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_changed', 10, 4 );
```