# Set custom status if WooCommerce order has items from a certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

Via the following code I added a custom order status (Abonnement) in WooCommerce

```php
function register_abonnement_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-abonnement', array(
        'label'                     => 'Abonnement',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'abonnement (%s)', 'abonnement (%s)' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_abonnement_order_status' );

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_abonnement_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
 
    $new_order_statuses = array();
 
    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
 
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
 
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-abonnement'] = 'Abonnement';
        }
    }
 
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_abonnement_to_order_statuses' );
```

---

I then used [Change WooCommerce order status based on approved status and specific order item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049885/11987538) answer code to help me further.

I modified that answer to go to the next step:

```php
    function action_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
// Compare
    if( $old_status === 'processing' ) {
        // Get items
        $items = $order->get_items();

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            // Get products categories
           global $post;
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
            break;
            }
            $product_cat = $item->get_product_cat();

            if ($product_cat == 249 ) {
                $order->update_status( 'abonnement' );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_changed');
```

But that doesn't seems to work. So i'm not sure what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

- Explanation via comment tags added in the code

To automatically change the order status after each order, when the order contains items that belong to certain categories, use:

```php
/**
 * Change Order Status
 */
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) return;

    // Get order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
    $categories = array( 'categorie-1', 'categorie-2', 15, 16 );
    
    // Flag
    $found = false;
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Product ID
        $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();

        // Has term (product category)
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        // Status without the "wc-" prefix || Some options: pending, processing, on-hold, completed, cancelled, refunded, failed, etc...
        $order->update_status( 'abonnement' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

**OR** using `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook where you can target your orders statuses transition `from` and `to`, to change the order status to any other.

```php
function action_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $old_status === 'processing' ) {
        // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
        $categories = array( 'categorie-1', 'categorie-2', 15, 16 );
        
        // Flag
        $found = false;
        
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Product ID
            $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();

            // Has term (product category)
            if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // True
        if ( $found ) {
            // Status without the "wc-" prefix || Some options: pending, processing, on-hold, completed, cancelled, refunded, failed, etc...
            $order->update_status( 'abonnement' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_changed', 10, 4 );
```

---

---

**Optional:** to register a new order status, you can replace your current code with this updated code

```php
/**
 * Register Order Status
 */
function filter_woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    // Status must start with "wc-"
    $order_statuses['wc-abonnement'] = array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Abonnement', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        /* translators: %s: number of orders */
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Abonnement <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Abonnement <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' ),       
    );
    
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', 'filter_woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Show Order Status in the Dropdown @ Single Order
 */
function filter_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    // Status must start with "wc-"
    $order_statuses['wc-abonnement'] = _x( 'Abonnement', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'filter_wc_order_statuses', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Show Order Status in the Dropdown @ Bulk Actions
 */
function filter_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order( $bulk_actions ) {
    // Note: "mark_" must be there instead of "wc"
    $bulk_actions['mark_abonnement'] = __( 'Change status to abonnement', 'woocommerce' );
    return $bulk_actions;
}
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'filter_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: I can't get the automatically order status change to work. That's why I tried with the Cat Id instead of the name array. But that didn't seem to work.

Comment: The only way to find what it doesn't work is through debugging, For example, you could set the flag variable by default to true, so that you can determine whether the code does something on its own without the category conditions.