# Is it possible to highlight these statuses in colors like other statuses updated by default from woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to change the color of order statuses as I created more custom order status and its color is by default is silver which I want to change, here is a code which I used to create new custom order status. I request you to help me to modify the below code to add color in the background in order status like other default status has already updated by woocommerce.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_statuses_as_order_status' );
function register_custom_statuses_as_order_status() {

    register_post_status( 'wc-postponed', array(
        'label'                     => __('Postponed'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Postponed <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Postponed <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );

    register_post_status( 'wc-verification', array(
        'label'                     => __('Verification'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Verification <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Verification <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_additional_custom_statuses_to_order_statuses' );
function add_additional_custom_statuses_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();
    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-postponed'] = __('Postponed');
            $new_order_statuses['wc-verification'] = __('Verification');
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom order status background button color in Woocommerce 3.3 admin order list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333542/custom-order-status-background-button-color-in-woocommerce-3-3-admin-order-list)

Comment: **Another note:** If you want to add a custom order status, you can use [this improved code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65898988/11987538) instead. **See:** optional - the **bottom part of the answer**