# Set WooCommerce order status when order contains a specific item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

Am trying to set any order that has the item ( item id 1511 ) to be set as 'processing'

I tried to play around with this code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049885/14188201), but without the desired result. I'm not sure what am doing wrong?

I tried going like this:

```php
function action_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $order_id, $new_status, $order ) {

        $items = $order->get_items();
        if ( $items as $item ) {
            // Get product id
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

            if ($product_id == 1511 ) {
                $order->update_status( 'processing' );
                break;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_changed', 10, 4 );
```

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`woocommerce_order_status_changed` action hook is triggered each time when order status change.

So for your question use the `woocommerce_checkout_order_created` hook (that is executed, before the e-mail notifications are sent) or the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook depending on your wishes.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_created( $order ) {
    // Already contains the correct status
    if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) return;
    
    // Set variable
    $found = false;
    
    // Get order items = each product in the order
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

        if ( $product_id == 1511 ) {
            $found = true;
            // true, break loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 10, 1 );
```

OR

```php
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Get order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Already contains the correct status
    if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) return;
    
    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    // Get order items = each product in the order
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

        if ( $product_id == 1511 ) {
            $found = true;
            // true, break loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. For the first code it kinda works, but when the customer click submit order to be redirected to the payment page, it actually redirect him to the thank you page and mark the order "processing" without even paying.

For the second one, it did not work actually. 

But you do get exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I count get around this, with all possible way i thought of. I tried to make a custom status, I tried to make it ( not paid status ), I tried to trigger the "pending" status, all results on going to ( Thank you page ) without redirections to payment page.